# passing value from 1 .htm file to another .html file without submitting

Tags: javascript, html

Im having a .html page which contains a set of value, when clicking on next button it will go to second .html file. I want to display the value in first .html files into second without submitting the first form and using javasript

Im tried to store that value in a javascript global variable and tried to get that from second html, but im not getting the values.

In first .html file , ill click on a next link that will redirect it to the second .html file

Is it a good idea to do with this cookies ?, im working for an enterprise project.

Comment: Are the pages in the same domain? Is the page opened with a new window or in the same browser window?

Comment: Your question is a little unclear. You can't use Javascript or you want to do it using Javascript?

Comment: Does _without submitting the first form and using javascript_ mean without submitting and without using javascript?

Comment: @epascarello : all are in the same domain , no its open a new html page in the same browser

Comment: @Cfreak :i want to use javascript, im trying with that, but i didnt get the desired result

Comment: Couldn't this be done by using cookies?

Answer (score 1):

I think this would be impossible.

The only way to get data from the page is to submit it to the server and process form values or use the javascript on the client side.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this by creating a link that looks like a button and adding the value from first page into the querystring of the url being linked to.

I'll draw up a quick demo in a moment.

**UPDATE**

Here's a quick demo of the kind of thing you'd need to do. This is using plain Javascript and would be much easier with jQuery:

http://jsfiddle.net/Mb2fM/

**UPDATE 2**

Here's an updated version using jQuery that correctly handles the change event and updates the querystring on the button: http://jsfiddle.net/Mb2fM/1/

Comment: What don't you get? The link to the second page (the button) passes the value from the first page via the querystring. This means the value you type into the box will be available on the second page for use.

Comment: im having a list of values, and also there is a checkbox, i ned to check which all the checkbox are checked, all these need to be performed in between.

Comment: You can attach as many querstring key/value pairs as you need.

Comment: but how can i perform the checks

Comment: cant i store this value in some javascript function and set this in other file using its id

Answer (score 0):

You can either pass the value in the querystring and read it from there.

If you do not want to change the url, you can use [localstorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/dom/storage) or [cookies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/document.cookie). Set the localstorage/cookie right before you leave the page. On the page load of the next page read the localstorage/cookie and use the value.

Comment: how can i do this using localstorage

Comment: im calling a javascript function on the next click, but i cnt retrieve tht value on second .html file

Comment: "but i cnt retrieve tht value on second .html file" and that means what? You can not write code on the second page?

Comment: im not getting the values in second html page

Comment: function getValue()document.getElementById('secondpagevalue').innerHTML  = document.getElementById('firstpagevalue).value } im calling this function on clicking next link in the first .html page. but im not geting the reult

Comment: Your solution does not use cookies or localstorage at all. You are trying to read elements that no longer exist. :)

Answer (score 0):

I think something which might work for you and is simple, is to use hidden form fields.
The first page submits the form to the second page, whose form has hidden fields to contain the data from the first page.  So you can access info from the previous form and process it as necessary before submitting the final form from the second page.

Haven't done this for a long time, but looking up hidden form fields will provide you with some examples.